# Where is a good place to farm Cloth scraps?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm trying to level up leather working, but I'm having a lot of trouble since I require a lot of Jute in order to do so, but it seems to be fairly rare. I'm currently level 30,  and my Leather working is only 49, so I think it's under leveled.

What mobs and locations are good for quickly farming Jute scraps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Ore and Wood, Leather and Cloth can only be obtained from salvaging items, or found in "Goodie Bags" that are sometimes dropped by humanoid monsters.

The idea, then, is to kill humanoids for their gear (which you can salvage) and their bags (which have a chance to obtain Jute, Wool, or what have you).

Common suggestions would include both Centaur and Bandit camps, of the appropriate level (mob level 20 and below).